# Can method parameters be dynamic in C#

Tags: dynamic, parameters, methods, c#-4.0

In c# 4.0, are dynamic method parameters possible, like in the following code?

```
public string MakeItQuack(dynamic duck)
{
  string quack = duck.Quack();
  return quack;
}
```

I've many cool examples of the dynamic keyword in C# 4.0, but not like above. This question is of course inspired by how python works.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do that. For the purposes of static overload resolution, it's treated as an `object` parameter (and called statically). What you do within the method will then be dynamic. For example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Foo(dynamic duck)
    {
        duck.Quack(); // Called dynamically
    }

    static void Foo(Guid ignored)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        // Calls Foo(dynamic) statically
        Foo("hello");
    }
}
```

The "dynamic is like object" nature means you can't have one overload with just an `object` parameter and one with just a `dynamic` parameter.

Comment: If I'm correctly understanding this updated article by ChrisB (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cburrows/archive/2010/04/01/errata-dynamic-conversions-and-overload-resolution.aspx) then it seems this behavior may have changed. Sounds like calls are always dispatched dynamically, with the overload chosen according to the type(s) of the parameters as determined at runtime.

Comment: @BitMask777: Only if one of the *arguments* (or target) is dynamic. So in the code in my answer, the `Foo("hello")` doesn't have any dynamic arguments, so `Foo(dyanmic)` is statically bound.

Answer (score 4):

See documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that. As stated in C# 4.0 specification, the grammar is extended to support `dynamic` wherever a *type* is expected:

> *type*:
>               ...
>              `dynamic`

This includes parameter definitions, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; see e.g.

http://blogs.msdn.com/cburrows/archive/2008/11/14/c-dynamic-part-vi.aspx

or Chris' other blogs.  Or grab VS2010 Beta2 and try it out.

Comment: Note that that article implies very inefficient late binding. Strong typing is your friend!

Comment: @David: The dynamic behaviour in the DLR is pretty neatly done to be as efficient as is sanely possible. Yes, it's late-bound, but it's not as inefficient as you might expect.