# Are there any guidelines for declaring a method which accepts an anonymous object as its argument?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to write a method that accepts an anonymous object as its argument. When declaring such a method should the parameter be declared as `object` or `dynamic`?

1. `public static void DoSomethingWith(dynamic details) { }` OR
2. `public static void DoSomethingWith(object details) { }`

My application is a standalone application targetting .NET 4.0.

One reason why I seem to prefer 1 is because when you see the IntelliSense tip that shows the signature of the method, a `dynamic` argument more clearly states its intent than `object`.

I will stick with 1 unless there are better reasons to go with 2.

What have been your experiences with this?

Comment: Depends on what you plan to do with this object in your method. You will not be able to access members of that object it you declare parameter as `object` (without reflection).

Comment: Did you mean http://stackoverflow.com/a/1723921/570150

Comment: Re " a dynamic argument more clearly states its intent than object" - how so? I don't think that is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hugely dependent on context. There are two existing answers shown that discuss the feature of `dynamic` that allows access to members, but there is a **huge** problem there in that it is not obvious to the caller that they *are meant to provide* those members. In those cases, a type that *has* those members would, in virtually all cases, be preferred.

In the main, usage of `dynamic` should be limited to those scenarios where you actually need it (talking to a dynamic type). If you are actually talking to a regular POCO object (maybe an anonymous type, etc), then `object` might avoid a few complications - but fundamentally `object` and `dynamic` are both implemented as `object` until you start accessing members.

Generally if you are passing a naked `object` to a method, you will be expecting the method to inspect it, perhaps via reflection. For those purposes, `object` will be absolutely fine, and provides direct access to `.GetType().GetProperties()` etc without any indirection.

Basically: without more context on what you are doing inside the method, it is impossible to conclude that either is "better" or "more appropriate", and *inside* the method `dynamic` and `object` are trivially interchangeable (a cast will always succeed, in either direction).

Comment: In my scenario the method is just a wrapper for a logging framework. This logging framework just dumps out all the property values in the argument that is passed.
The reason why i feel a dynamic more clearly states its intent is because when i look at a method that takes a dynamic argument i tend to associate it with an anonymous object. But that's just me.

Comment: @SAK `dynamic` is largely unrelated to "anonymous". Indeed, `object` suggests: "reflection", where-as `dynamic` suggests `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. I'm guessing you're going to access it by reflection, yes? For my money: `object`.

Comment: Actually, I wont be accessing it at all. I will be passing it along to API that needs it. That API will indeed use reflection to dump it out to the log, but my code does nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are targetting framework 4.0 or higher, then its better to use dynamic.

```
public static void DoSomethingWith(dynamic details)
{
    Console.Write(details.X);
    Console.Write(details.Y);
}
```

And call it like:

```
DoSomethingWith(new { X = "ABC", Y = 10 });
```

Comment: "better" is relative and depends on the intended usage; I disagree with a blanket claim of "better", without more context. If your object is expected to have `.X` and `.Y`, then frankly it would be better to type the parameter to a class, struct, or interface that **has** a `.X` and `.Y`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, using `dynamic` has some advantages over `object` and no disadvantages that I can see, so your option 1 is clearly the way to go.

Option 1 allows you to use your parameter just as if you had declared it with the real type (which you can't do, since it is anonymous):

```
public static void DoSomethingWith(dynamic details)
{
  var temp = details.Property; // Correct, as long as the object has a property called Property
}
```

With option 2, this code would have been illegal and you would have to resort to `InvokeMethod()` and the like, which is more cumbersome to use and to read without providing any real advantages.

Comment: Those "advantages" are entirely context specific; if you expect a `.Property`, then it would be better to type the parameter as something that **has** a `.Property`; otherwise the **major** disadvantage is discoverability: how does the caller know that they are meant to provide a `.Property` ?