# Letting the compiler know that a Generic has a field

Tags: c#, .net

So let's say I'm gonna have a method with a Generic Type called getCountry:

```
public T GetCountry<T>(int portalID)
{
    T theCountry = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    theCountry.id = "AR";
    if(portalID == 1) theCountry.id = "ARG";
    return theCountry;
}
```

Of course this doesn't work, because the compiler does not know that T has a field called "id" inside.

I can't do alternate solutions like placing the `where T extends AbstractCountry` or whatever because those country classes are top classes and I don't have access to the code to make a parent for them. The code's not mine (and unfortunately is very poorly designed). This means that I also can't make a constructor for the different country types and send the id as a parameter using the Activator class, and personally that's where my knowledge of generics ends.

Is there any way I can achieve what I'm trying to do? Thanks everyone!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dynamic` when creating the instance, which allows you to use arbitrary members on it ("late binding"). A runtime error will be thrown if `T` has no property or field with that name.

Cast the object back to `T` before returning it.

```
public T GetCountry<T>(int portalID)
{
    dynamic theCountry = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    theCountry.id = "AR";
    if(portalID == 1) theCountry.id = "ARG";
    return (T)theCountry;
}
```

Comment: Yes, by the time you said your PS I had already edited the post. That was fast geez. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the [`dynamic` feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) in C#, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723875/can-method-parameters-be-dynamic-in-c-sharp).

Answer (score 2):

As opposed to `dynamic` feature you can use generic parameter constraints

```
public interface IIdentifier
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}

public static T GetCountry<T>(int portalID) where T : IIdentifier
{
    T theCountry = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
    theCountry.Id = "AR";
    if (portalID == 1) theCountry.Id = "ARG";
    return theCountry;
}
```

`IIdentifier` can be some base type which has all the properties you need. If there is no common base type then `dynamic` is the way to go.

Worth noting that when you use dynamic with the type which has no member named `Id` that will fail in runtime, but when you use generic constraints you will not be able to compile it which will be good rather than failing silently at runtime.

Comment: Yes there is no common interface or whatever as I stated in my question. I can't edit them either. It's a shame =(. Thanks!

Comment: @Damieh If no common base type then use `dynamic`. be sure you read my edit.